# pushing a tagged image in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I hjave a sample jenkins code as below:

```
node {
    def app

    stage('Clone repository') {
        /* Let's make sure we have the repository cloned to our workspace */
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Build and Push image') {
        docker.withRegistry('https://container-registry.oracle.com', 'container-hub-credentials') {
            sh """
                echo `pwd`

            """
        }


        docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
            sh """
                echo `pwd`
                docker build --build-arg ADMIN_PASS=weblogic123 --build-arg ADMIN_USER=weblogic -t wls-12213-domain .
                docker build -t leexha/wls-12213-oow-demo-domain  -f Dockerfile.adddemoapps .
                docker build -t leexha/oow-demo-webhook -f Dockerfile.webhook .
                docker push leexha/wls-12213-oow-demo-domain
                docker push leexha/oow-demo-webhook


            """
        }
    }
}
```

but it keeps telling me that

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

When i try pushing.

I already created my repo in docker hub. So what gives?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is on the the access right of the docker hub user you use in the docker registry credentials.

Validiate you can n push a docker when you are logged as that docker hub user.

`docker login -u username -p password`

`docker push image-name`

If that succeed, validate you docker socket can be used by the Jenkins user.

Comment: So i can access as sudo su -jenkins bin/bash . I then did a push and it went through. So how do i validate socket can be used by jenkins user

Comment: In fact in my docker file i am doing a docker pull which was able to pull and build through docker.hub.io. I just cant push

Comment: In fact, bash-4.2$ groups
jenkins docker